# scheme using lambda

Tags: lambda, scheme

I have a piece of code in scheme that uses several lambdas. It basically returns a number that's in the middle.

```
(define foo
  (lambda (x)
    (letrec
      ((h (lambda (y z)
        (cond
          ((null? y) 'undefined)
          ((null? (cdr y)) (car z))
          (else (h (cddr y) (cdr z)))))))
  ((lambda (y) (h y y)) x))))
```

I have to rewrite the code so it doesn't use any lambda. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context and what you have been taught. If you post more context, you'll most likely get a better answer.

However, note first, that

```
(define (foo x) (+ x 1))
```

is equivalent to

```
(define foo (lambda (x) (+ x 1))).
```

To get rid of `letrec` rewrite it to an internal definition.

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to simplify the code to:(define (foo x)
    (letrec
      ((h (lambda (y z)
        (cond
          ((null? y) 'undefined)
          ((null? (cdr y)) (car z))
          (else (h (cddr y) (cdr z)))))))
  (h x x))) but am not sure how to remove the last lambda (maybe some inner define?)

Comment: See http://icem.folkwang-hochschule.de/~finnendahl/cm_kurse/doc/schintro/schintro_126.html

Answer (score 4):

To remove all the lambdas in the expression you can do this:

- Replace the procedure definition from this form: `(define f (lambda (x) x))` to this equivalent form: `(define (f x) x)`
- Replace the `letrec` expression with an internal definition
- Replace the `lambda` in the last line with another internal definition, naming it and calling it at the end
- Even simpler: notice that you don't really need the last `lambda`, as is equivalent to directly calling `(h x x)`

After successively applying each of the above replacements, the procedure ends up looking like this:

```
(define (foo x)
  (define (h y z)
    (cond
      ((null? y) 'undefined)
      ((null? (cdr y)) (car z))
      (else (h (cddr y) (cdr z)))))
  (h x x))
```

Notice that the `lambda`s are not *really* eliminated, they're still there under the hood - hidden behind some syntactic sugar.